# Configuring embedded Derby in Sqoop2

Tags: configuration, derby, sqoop2

I want to set up Sqoop2. But there is some problem in configuring it. When I start the server by `sqoop2-server start` it does not give any errors on console but it fails to start and it shows errors in the log.

Console output:

```
Sqoop home directory: /opt/sqoop-1.99.6
Setting SQOOP_HTTP_PORT:     12000
Setting SQOOP_ADMIN_PORT:     12001
Using   CATALINA_OPTS:       
Adding to CATALINA_OPTS:    -Dsqoop.http.port=12000 -Dsqoop.admin.port=12001
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/sqoop-1.99.6/server
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/sqoop-1.99.6/server
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/sqoop-1.99.6/server/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /opt/jdk1.8.0_51/jre
Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/sqoop-1.99.6/server/bin/bootstrap.jar
```

The main error seems to be:

`ERROR XSLAN: Database at /opt/sqoop-1.99.6/repository/db has an incompatible format with the current version of the software.  The database was created by or upgraded by version 10.10`

Here is the complete log:

```
2015-08-18 12:00:44,932 INFO  authentication.SimpleAuthenticationHandler [org.apache.sqoop.security.authentication.SimpleAuthenticationHandler.secureLogin(SimpleAuthenticationHandler.java:40)] Using simple/pseudo authentication, principal [root]
2015-08-18 12:00:44,932 INFO  security.AuthenticationManager [org.apache.sqoop.security.AuthenticationManager.initialize(AuthenticationManager.java:102)] Authentication loaded.
2015-08-18 12:00:44,937 INFO  security.AuthorizationManager [org.apache.sqoop.security.AuthorizationManager.initialize(AuthorizationManager.java:117)] Authorization loaded.
2015-08-18 12:00:44,938 INFO  audit.AuditLoggerManager [org.apache.sqoop.audit.AuditLoggerManager.initialize(AuditLoggerManager.java:80)] Begin audit logger manager initialization
2015-08-18 12:00:44,939 WARN  audit.FileAuditLogger [org.apache.sqoop.audit.FileAuditLogger.initialize(FileAuditLogger.java:68)] appender: log4j.appender.defaultAppender
2015-08-18 12:00:44,940 INFO  audit.AuditLoggerManager [org.apache.sqoop.audit.AuditLoggerManager.initializeLoggers(AuditLoggerManager.java:127)] Audit Logger has been initialized: default
2015-08-18 12:00:44,941 INFO  audit.AuditLoggerManager [org.apache.sqoop.audit.AuditLoggerManager.initialize(AuditLoggerManager.java:86)] Audit logger manager initialized: OK
2015-08-18 12:00:44,942 INFO  repository.RepositoryManager [org.apache.sqoop.repository.RepositoryManager.initialize(RepositoryManager.java:86)] Setting system properties: {derby.stream.error.file=/var/log/sqoop/derbyrepo.log}
2015-08-18 12:00:44,948 INFO  repository.JdbcRepositoryContext [org.apache.sqoop.repository.JdbcRepositoryContext.<init>(JdbcRepositoryContext.java:154)] [repo-ctx] handler=org.apache.sqoop.repository.derby.DerbyRepositoryHandler, conn-url=jdbc:derby:/opt/sqoop-1.99.6/repository/db;create=true, driver=org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver, user=sa, password=*****, jdbc-props={}, tx-isolation=READ_COMMITTED, max-conn=10
2015-08-18 12:00:45,260 INFO  derby.DerbyRepositoryHandler [org.apache.sqoop.repository.derby.DerbyRepositoryHandler.initialize(DerbyRepositoryHandler.java:96)] DerbyRepositoryHandler initialized.
2015-08-18 12:00:45,263 INFO  repository.JdbcRepositoryProvider [org.apache.sqoop.repository.JdbcRepositoryProvider.initializeRepositoryHandler(JdbcRepositoryProvider.java:160)] JdbcRepositoryProvider initialized
2015-08-18 12:00:45,263 INFO  repository.JdbcRepositoryProvider [org.apache.sqoop.repository.JdbcRepositoryProvider.initialize(JdbcRepositoryProvider.java:67)] JdbcRepository initialized.
2015-08-18 12:00:45,263 INFO  repository.RepositoryManager [org.apache.sqoop.repository.RepositoryManager.initialize(RepositoryManager.java:122)] Creating or updating respository at bootup
2015-08-18 12:00:45,341 DEBUG repository.JdbcRepositoryTransaction [org.apache.sqoop.repository.JdbcRepositoryTransaction.close(JdbcRepositoryTransaction.java:103)] Tx count-close: -1, rollback: false
2015-08-18 12:00:45,343 ERROR core.SqoopServer [org.apache.sqoop.core.SqoopServer.initialize(SqoopServer.java:62)] Server startup failure
org.apache.sqoop.common.SqoopException: JDBCREPO_0007:Unable to lease link
    at org.apache.sqoop.repository.JdbcRepositoryTransaction.begin(JdbcRepositoryTransaction.java:63)
    at org.apache.sqoop.repository.JdbcRepository.doWithConnection(JdbcRepository.java:87)
    at org.apache.sqoop.repository.JdbcRepository.doWithConnection(JdbcRepository.java:63)
    at org.apache.sqoop.repository.JdbcRepository.createOrUpgradeRepository(JdbcRepository.java:129)
    at org.apache.sqoop.repository.RepositoryManager.initialize(RepositoryManager.java:123)
    at org.apache.sqoop.repository.RepositoryManager.initialize(RepositoryManager.java:77)
    at org.apache.sqoop.core.SqoopServer.initialize(SqoopServer.java:56)
    at org.apache.sqoop.server.ServerInitializer.contextInitialized(ServerInitializer.java:41)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:778)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database '/opt/sqoop-1.99.6/repository/db' with class loader WebappClassLoader
  context: /sqoop
  delegate: false
  repositories:
    /WEB-INF/classes/
----------> Parent Classloader:
org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader@4783da3f
, see the next exception for details.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.newEmbedSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.seeNextException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.bootDatabase(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection30.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection40.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.Driver40.getNewEmbedConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverManagerConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverManagerConnectionFactory.java:78)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1148)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:106)
    at org.apache.sqoop.repository.JdbcRepositoryTransaction.begin(JdbcRepositoryTransaction.java:61)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database '/opt/sqoop-1.99.6/repository/db' with class loader WebappClassLoader
  context: /sqoop
  delegate: false
  repositories:
    /WEB-INF/classes/
----------> Parent Classloader:
org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader@4783da3f
, see the next exception for details.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Database at /opt/sqoop-1.99.6/repository/db has an incompatible format with the current version of the software.  The database was created by or upgraded by version 10.10.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: ERROR XSLAN: Database at /opt/sqoop-1.99.6/repository/db has an incompatible format with the current version of the software.  The database was created by or upgraded by version 10.10.
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.log.LogToFile.readControlFile(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.log.LogToFile.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.bootServiceModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.bootLogFactory(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.setRawStoreFactory(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.RawStore.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.bootServiceModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.RAMAccessManager.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.bootServiceModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase.bootStore(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.bootService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startProviderService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.findProviderAndStartService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startPersistentService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.startPersistentService(Unknown Source)
    ... 45 more
2015-08-18 12:00:45,346 ERROR server.ServerInitializer [org.apache.sqoop.server.ServerInitializer.contextInitialized(ServerInitializer.java:46)] Sqoop server failed to start
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure in server initialization
    at org.apache.sqoop.core.SqoopServer.initialize(SqoopServer.java:63)
    at org.apache.sqoop.server.ServerInitializer.contextInitialized(ServerInitializer.java:41)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:778)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: org.apache.sqoop.common.SqoopException: JDBCREPO_0007:Unable to lease link
    at org.apache.sqoop.repository.JdbcRepositoryTransaction.begin(JdbcRepositoryTransaction.java:63)
    at org.apache.sqoop.repository.JdbcRepository.doWithConnection(JdbcRepository.java:87)
    at org.apache.sqoop.repository.JdbcRepository.doWithConnection(JdbcRepository.java:63)
    at org.apache.sqoop.repository.JdbcRepository.createOrUpgradeRepository(JdbcRepository.java:129)
    at org.apache.sqoop.repository.RepositoryManager.initialize(RepositoryManager.java:123)
    at org.apache.sqoop.repository.RepositoryManager.initialize(RepositoryManager.java:77)
    at org.apache.sqoop.core.SqoopServer.initialize(SqoopServer.java:56)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database '/opt/sqoop-1.99.6/repository/db' with class loader WebappClassLoader
  context: /sqoop
  delegate: false
  repositories:
    /WEB-INF/classes/
----------> Parent Classloader:
org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader@4783da3f
, see the next exception for details.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.newEmbedSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.seeNextException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.bootDatabase(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection30.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection40.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.Driver40.getNewEmbedConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverManagerConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverManagerConnectionFactory.java:78)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1148)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:106)
    at org.apache.sqoop.repository.JdbcRepositoryTransaction.begin(JdbcRepositoryTransaction.java:61)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database '/opt/sqoop-1.99.6/repository/db' with class loader WebappClassLoader
  context: /sqoop
  delegate: false
  repositories:
    /WEB-INF/classes/
----------> Parent Classloader:
org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader@4783da3f
, see the next exception for details.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Database at /opt/sqoop-1.99.6/repository/db has an incompatible format with the current version of the software.  The database was created by or upgraded by version 10.10.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: ERROR XSLAN: Database at /opt/sqoop-1.99.6/repository/db has an incompatible format with the current version of the software.  The database was created by or upgraded by version 10.10.
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.log.LogToFile.readControlFile(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.log.LogToFile.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.bootServiceModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.bootLogFactory(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.setRawStoreFactory(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.RawStore.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.bootServiceModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.RAMAccessManager.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.bootServiceModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase.bootStore(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.bootService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startProviderService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.findProviderAndStartService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startPersistentService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.startPersistentService(Unknown Source)
    ... 45 more
```

sqoop.properties:

```
# Logging Configuration
# Any property that starts with the prefix
# org.apache.sqoop.log4j is parsed out by the configuration
# system and passed to the log4j subsystem. This allows you
# to specify log4j configuration properties from within the
# Sqoop configuration.
#
org.apache.sqoop.log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
org.apache.sqoop.log4j.appender.file.File=/var/log/sqoop/sqoop.log
org.apache.sqoop.log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=25MB
org.apache.sqoop.log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=5
org.apache.sqoop.log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
org.apache.sqoop.log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %-5p %c{2} [%l] %m%n
org.apache.sqoop.log4j.debug=true
org.apache.sqoop.log4j.rootCategory=WARN, file
org.apache.sqoop.log4j.category.org.apache.sqoop=DEBUG
org.apache.sqoop.log4j.category.org.apache.derby=INFO

#
# Audit Loggers Configuration
# Multiple audit loggers could be given here. To specify an
# audit logger, you should at least add org.apache.sqoop.
# auditlogger.[LoggerName].class. You could also provide
# more configuration options by using org.apache.sqoop.
# auditlogger.[LoggerName] prefix, then all these options
# are parsed to the logger class.
#
org.apache.sqoop.auditlogger.default.class=org.apache.sqoop.audit.FileAuditLogger
org.apache.sqoop.auditlogger.default.file=/var/log/sqoop/default.audit

#
# Repository configuration
# The Repository subsystem provides the special prefix which
# is "org.apache.sqoop.repository.sysprop". Any property that
# is specified with this prefix is parsed out and set as a
# system property. For example, if the built in Derby repository
# is being used, the sysprop prefixed properties can be used
# to affect Derby configuration at startup time by setting
# the appropriate system properties.
#

# Repository provider
org.apache.sqoop.repository.provider=org.apache.sqoop.repository.JdbcRepositoryProvider

# Repository upgrade
# If set to true, it will not upgrade the sqoop respository schema, by default it will iniate the upgrade on server start-up
org.apache.sqoop.repository.schema.immutable=false

# JDBC repository provider configuration
org.apache.sqoop.repository.jdbc.handler=org.apache.sqoop.repository.derby.DerbyRepositoryHandler
org.apache.sqoop.repository.jdbc.transaction.isolation=READ_COMMITTED
org.apache.sqoop.repository.jdbc.maximum.connections=10
org.apache.sqoop.repository.jdbc.url=jdbc:derby:/opt/sqoop-1.99.6/repository/db;create=true
org.apache.sqoop.repository.jdbc.driver=org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
org.apache.sqoop.repository.jdbc.user=sa
org.apache.sqoop.repository.jdbc.password=

# System properties for embedded Derby configuration
org.apache.sqoop.repository.sysprop.derby.stream.error.file=/var/log/sqoop/derbyrepo.log

#
# Sqoop Connector configuration
# If set to true will initiate Connectors config upgrade during server startup
#
org.apache.sqoop.connector.autoupgrade=false

#
# Sqoop Driver configuration
# If set to true will initiate the Driver config upgrade during server startup
#
org.apache.sqoop.driver.autoupgrade=false

# Sleeping period for reloading configuration file (once a minute)
org.apache.sqoop.core.configuration.provider.properties.sleep=60000

#
# Submission engine configuration
#

# Submission engine class
org.apache.sqoop.submission.engine=org.apache.sqoop.submission.mapreduce.MapreduceSubmissionEngine

# Number of milliseconds, submissions created before this limit will be removed, default is one day
#org.apache.sqoop.submission.purge.threshold=

# Number of milliseconds for purge thread to sleep, by default one day
#org.apache.sqoop.submission.purge.sleep=

# Number of milliseconds for update thread to sleep, by default 5 minutes
#org.apache.sqoop.submission.update.sleep=

#
# Configuration for Mapreduce submission engine (applicable if it's configured)
#

# Hadoop configuration directory
org.apache.sqoop.submission.engine.mapreduce.configuration.directory=/opt/hadoop-2.7.1/etc/hadoop/

#
# Execution engine configuration
#
org.apache.sqoop.execution.engine=org.apache.sqoop.execution.mapreduce.MapreduceExecutionEngine

#
# Authentication configuration
#
#org.apache.sqoop.security.authentication.type=SIMPLE
#org.apache.sqoop.security.authentication.handler=org.apache.sqoop.security.authentication.SimpleAuthenticationHandler
#org.apache.sqoop.security.authentication.anonymous=true
#org.apache.sqoop.security.authentication.type=KERBEROS
#org.apache.sqoop.security.authentication.handler=org.apache.sqoop.security.authentication.KerberosAuthenticationHandler
#org.apache.sqoop.security.authentication.kerberos.principal=sqoop/_HOST@NOVALOCAL
#org.apache.sqoop.security.authentication.kerberos.keytab=/home/kerberos/sqoop.keytab
#org.apache.sqoop.security.authentication.kerberos.http.principal=HTTP/_HOST@NOVALOCAL
#org.apache.sqoop.security.authentication.kerberos.http.keytab=/home/kerberos/sqoop.keytab
#org.apache.sqoop.security.authentication.enable.doAs=true
#org.apache.sqoop.security.authentication.proxyuser.#USER#.users=*
#org.apache.sqoop.security.authentication.proxyuser.#USER#.groups=*
#org.apache.sqoop.security.authentication.proxyuser.#USER#.hosts=*

#
# Authorization configuration
#
#org.apache.sqoop.security.authorization.handler=org.apache.sqoop.security.authorization.DefaultAuthorizationHandler
#org.apache.sqoop.security.authorization.access_controller=org.apache.sqoop.security.authorization.DefaultAuthorizationAccessController
#org.apache.sqoop.security.authorization.validator=org.apache.sqoop.security.authorization.DefaultAuthorizationValidator
#org.apache.sqoop.security.authorization.authentication_provider=org.apache.sqoop.security.authorization.DefaultAuthenticationProvider
#org.apache.sqoop.security.authorization.server_name=SqoopServer1

# External connectors load path
# "/path/to/external/connectors/": Add all the connector JARs in the specified folder
#
org.apache.sqoop.connector.external.loadpath=
```

I think the problem has some thing to do with embedded derby. Can someone help me find where the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the @BASEDIR@/repository/db which in my case is /opt/sqoop-1.99.6/repository/db and again started the server. I am not sure if this is a good method but this worked for me.